# Indent specific individual paragraphs of a UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring, nsparagraphstyle

I'm building up the textual content of a `UITextView`, by adding individual paragraphs one at a time to an `NSMutableAttributedString`. Some of these paragraphs need to be indented, as they are hierarchical, as in:

```
1. ...    
   (a). ... 
       (i). ...
       (ii). ...
   (b). ...
...
```

To (try to) do the indentation, I'm using this code:

```
let paraStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paraStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = CGFloat(indentLevel * 20)
paraStyle.headIndent = CGFloat(indentLevel * 20) 
attrText.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: paraStyle, range:NSRange(location: 0, length: attrText.length))
```

and finally

```
textView.attributedText = attrText
```

where `indentLevel` indicates how much a given paragraph is to be indented.

When I look at the final attributed text in the debugger, I can see the correct paragraph styling is in place, but the text on-screen is NOT indented at all; everything is left-justified.

What am I missing/misunderstanding about styling paragraphs using attributed strings in a `UITextView`?

Comment: Do you intend on editing the text? just a thought that it would have been easier with a UILabel?

Comment: No, it will be display-only (non-editable, but selectable).  I chose the UITextView because there will be custom links within the text, and UITextView gives me that functionality for free.

Comment: I'm curious, though, how you think UILabel would be any different/easier, in terms of my question, than UITextView?

Comment: Care to post your string as well. Where you create the attributed text

Comment: It's dynamic text, a series of plain ol' Strings read in from Core Data, each instance a single paragraph; one or more of these paragraphs are concatenated together to form the on-screen display.

Comment: This is essentially the code that does that:
    let attrText = NSMutableAttributedString()
let count = paragraphs.count
for i in 0..<count {
 let paragraph = paragraphs[i]
 if let text = paragraph.text, text.count > 0 {
  // Need an extra terminating space, because of aa apparent bug in NSMutableAttributedString:
  let formatted: NSMutableAttributedString = format("\(text) ", indentLevel: Int(paragraph.indent))
  attrText.append(formatted)
  if i < count-1 {
   attrText.append(NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\n"))
  }
 }
}

followed by the code in my original post.

Comment: The format() method applies a font to the entire range, and then seeks out and inserts custom URL links.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I would have thought a UILabel would be more likely to stick to your paragraph style, it sounds like the textview is overriding paragraphstyle